# What is the best way to override _forms/default.aspx?

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication

I've got FBA enabled. Created custom login page, which uses two factor authentication. It is all working fine, same as `/_forms/default.aspx`.

However, I'd not like users to use `/_forms/default.aspx` as a back-door and skip additional security check at login.

What is the the best approach for this scenario?

Comment: I can do that as modifying web.config for _forms:
<deny users="*" />

But it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the login page on the web application settings in Central Administration.  You would need to create a login page to replace it with.  There are a number of examples on the web, here is one you could start with: http://sivarajan.me/post/SharePoint-2013-Enabling-Custom-Login-Page-and-Mixed-Contents-Part-2

**EDIT**

To answer your revised question, you can redirect the page at the IIS level.  The URL Rewrite module for IIS could handle this for you: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite